# Use runtime optimized Javascript

Tags: xpages

I have the same problem described here on the [e-office blog](http://www.domino-weblog.nl/weblogs/Domino_Blog.nsf/dx/is-it-a-bug-xsp.resources.aggregate-and-firefox.htm?opendocument&comments#anc1) , but in my case it also happens in IE9. When I manually do a refresh of the page, everything is working again. It looks like the JS aggregator tries to do something with the javascript files.

Does anyone found a solution for this?

This is the way I load my client javascript files. The 'xast.locationJS' variable  is the location on the server where I the javascript files can be found.

```
   <xp:this.resources>
    <xp:script clientSide="true">
        <xp:this.src><![CDATA[${javascript:return  applicationScope.get("xast.serverUrl") +"/" +applicationScope.get("xast.locationJS") + "/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"}]]></xp:this.src>
    </xp:script>
    <xp:script clientSide="true">
        <xp:this.src><![CDATA[${javascript:return applicationScope.get("xast.serverUrl") + "/" + applicationScope.get("xast.locationJS") + "/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js"}]]></xp:this.src>
    </xp:script>
    <xp:script clientSide="true">
        <xp:this.src><![CDATA[${javascript:return  applicationScope.get("xast.serverUrl") + "/" + applicationScope.get("xast.locationJS") + "/jquery.tools.min.js"}]]></xp:this.src>
    </xp:script>
    <xp:script clientSide="true">
        <xp:this.src><![CDATA[${javascript:return  applicationScope.get("xast.serverUrl") + "/" + applicationScope.get("xast.locationJS") + "/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"}]]></xp:this.src>
    </xp:script>
    <xp:script clientSide="true">
        <xp:this.src><![CDATA[#{javascript:return  applicationScope.get("xast.serverUrl") + "/" + applicationScope.get("xast.locationJS") + "/C2C_dojo.tools.js"}]]></xp:this.src>
    </xp:script>
    <xp:script clientSide="true">
        <xp:this.src><![CDATA[#{javascript:return  applicationScope.get("xast.serverUrl") + "/" + applicationScope.get("xast.locationJS") + "/CommonXmlFunctions.js"}]]></xp:this.src>      
    </xp:script>
    <xp:script clientSide="true">
        <xp:this.src><![CDATA[#{javascript:return  applicationScope.get("xast.serverUrl") + "/" + applicationScope.get("xast.locationJS") + "/C2C_WebCaseSuggest.js"}]]></xp:this.src>
    </xp:script>
    <xp:script clientSide="true">
        <xp:this.src><![CDATA[${javascript:return  applicationScope.get("xast.serverUrl") + "/" + applicationScope.get("xast.locationJS") + "/uncompressed/xpUtils.js"}]]></xp:this.src>
    </xp:script>
</xp:this.resources>
```

Comment: Tongue-in-cheek: use Chrome Frame

Comment: Chrome Frame...yuk! This happens serverside I'm afraid, not related to any browser, it also happens in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Just a quick question: Is there any reason why some CSJS libraries are set to "Compute On Page Load" and some are set to "Compute Dynamically"?

Comment: I added some javascript later and left it to compute dynamically. But while I'm thinking about it, the compute on page load libraries are the ones that throw the errors the first time the page loads... mmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the 'compute on page load' property was the problem. I think libraries that are computed on page load wil be automatically picked up by the JS aggregator, or something like that.